# não consigo fazer com que aparece quantos alunos foram aprovados

Tags: c

Algoritmo para ler 2 notas de um aluno, calcular e imprimir a média final. Logo após escrever a mensagem "Calcular a média de outro aluno 1.Sim 2.Não?" e solicitar uma resposta. **Se a resposta for 1, o algoritmo deve ser executado novamente, caso contrário deve ser encerrado imprimindo a quantidade de alunos aprovados. Para ser aprovado o aluno tem que ter média maior ou igual a sete**

Segue meu código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  float nota1,nota2,media1,media2,nota3,nota4,mediaf=1;
  int resp;
  char aluno1[10],aluno2[10];
    while(resp==1)
    {
        printf("Informe o nome do aluno:");
        gets(aluno1);
            fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nDigite a primeira nota do aluno: ");
        scanf("%f",&nota1);
        printf("\nDigite a segunda nota: ");
        scanf("%f",&nota2);
            fflush(stdin);
        media1 = (nota1 + nota2)/2;
            fflush(stdin);
        printf("\na media de %ce : %0.0f\n",aluno1, media1);
        printf("\nDigite 1 para continuar ou 2 para sair: ");
        scanf("%d", &resp);

    }
  do
    {
            fflush(stdin);
        printf("Informe o nome do aluno:");
        gets(aluno2);
            fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nDigite a primeira nota: ");
        scanf("%f",&nota3);
        printf("\nDigite a segunda nota: ");
        scanf("%f",&nota4);
             fflush(stdin);
        media2 = (nota3 + nota4)/2;
        printf("\nMedia de %s e: %0.0f\n",aluno2,media2);
            fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nDigite 1 para continuar ou 2 para sair\n");
        scanf("%d", &resp);
    }   
  while (resp==1);

  return 0;
}


#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
  float nota1,nota2,media1,media2,nota3,nota4,mediaf=1;
  int resp;

char aluno1[10],aluno2[10];

    while(resp==1)
    {

        printf("Informe o nome do aluno:");

        gets(aluno1);

            fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nDigite a primeira nota do aluno: ");

        scanf("%f",&nota1);

        printf("\nDigite a segunda nota: ");

        scanf("%f",&nota2);

            fflush(stdin);

        media1 = (nota1 + nota2)/2;

            fflush(stdin);

        printf("\na media de %ce : %0.0f\n",aluno1, media1);

        printf("\nDigite 1 para continuar ou 2 para sair: ");

        scanf("%d", &resp);

    }
  do
    {

            fflush(stdin);

        printf("Informe o nome do aluno:");

        gets(aluno2);

            fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nDigite a primeira nota: ");

        scanf("%f",&nota3);

        printf("\nDigite a segunda nota: ");

        scanf("%f",&nota4);

             fflush(stdin);

        media2 = (nota3 + nota4)/2;

        printf("\nMedia de %s e: %0.0f\n",aluno2,media2);

            fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nDigite 1 para continuar ou 2 para sair\n");

        scanf("%d", &resp);

    }   

  while (resp==1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou adicionar um contador para cada inserção de aluno? exemplo some as quantidades das variaveis aluno1 e aluno2, claro o melhor seria você unificar essas variaveis. Tente trabalhar com case  em vez do do .... while, coloque um case 1 (EXECUTA O CÓDIGO) break case 2 exit break. Acredito que dará certo

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tudo bem?!

Vou lhe sugerir algumas alterações no seu código para que ele fique melhor:

1. Tem de ter mais cuidado com a forma como escreve o seu código e tentar mantê-lo o mais limpo e simples possível evitando repetições de linhas de código, por exemplo.
2. Em segundo lugar, não necessita de declarar tantas variáveis para resolver este problema. A gestão de memória utilizada é algo bastante importante e deve ter uma atenção especial com ela.
3. Além disso, lembre-se da estrutura de repetição do..while que lhe vai ajudar bastante a não cometer tantas repetições.
4. Por fim, tenha atenção à forma como são tratadas as variáveis do tipo char que armazenam mais caracteres. Para as exibir corretamente tem de utilizar o formato de leitura '%s' ao invés de '%c'.

Agora vou lhe mostrar a minha proposta de resolução do algoritmo. É bastante simples mas lembre-se: poderão existir resoluções ainda mais eficazes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  float nota1,nota2,media;
  int resp, aprovados;
  char aluno[10];
  aprovados = 0;
  do {
      printf("\nInforme o nome do aluno: ");
      scanf("%s", aluno);
  printf("\nDigite a primeira nota do aluno: ");
  scanf(" %f",&nota1);
  printf("\nDigite a segunda nota: ");
  scanf(" %f",&nota2);
  media = (nota1 + nota2)/2;
  printf("\nA media de %s e : %0.0f\n",aluno, media);
  if(media>=7){
    aprovados++;
  }
  printf("\nDigite 1 para continuar ou 2 para sair: ");
  scanf(" %d",&resp);
   }while( resp == 1 );
  printf("\nForam aprovados %d alunos.\n",aprovados);
 return 0;
}
```

Espero ter sido útil!

*nota: cada um tem o seu estilo de código e de indentação, por isso, escreva o código como lhe for mais confortável.*

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Refiz seu código de uma forma mais simples. Se tiver dúvidas, só perguntar.

```
insira o código aqui


#include <stdio.h>


int mediaParcial(){
float notaUm,notaDois,media;
int x,cont=0,escolha;

do{
printf("Calcular a média de um aluno\n");
printf("1.Sim 2.Não?\n");
scanf("%d",&escolha);
if(escolha==1){
fflush(stdin);
printf("Nota 1:");
scanf("%f",&notaUm);
printf("Nota 2:");
scanf("%f",&notaDois);
media=(notaUm+notaDois)/2;
if(media >= 7){
cont+=1;
}
}else{
break;
}
}while(escolha !=2);

 return cont;

 }

 int main(void) {
 int aprovados;
 aprovados=mediaParcial();
 printf("Foram Aprovados %d",aprovados);
 }
```